# Emu8086 Check if key is pressed

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16

I'm trying to check if the key "ESC" is press. If it's press I want the user to be able to enter text and print it right after.

I want the program to check anytime if they user press ESC.

This is my current code:

```
org 100h
include "emu8086.inc"


;mov ah, 01h
;int 16h

;mov ah, 00h
;int 16h

call cleanScreen

printn "      ___"     
printn "     /\  \"    
printn "    /::\  \"   
printn "   /:/\ \  \"  
printn "  _\:\~\ \  \" 
printn " /\ \:\ \ \__\"
printn " \:\ \:\ \/__/"
printn "  \:\ \:\__\ " 
printn "   \:\/:/  /"  
printn "    \::/  /"   
printn "     \/__/"
printn "Welcome to Sheridan"    

call cleanScreen

printn "      ___"    
printn "     /\__\"    
printn "    /:/ _/_"   
printn "   /:/ /\  \"  
printn "  /:/ /::\  \" 
printn " /:/_/:/\:\__\"
printn " \:\/:/ /:/  /"
printn "  \::/ /:/  /" 
printn "   \/_/:/  /"  
printn "     /:/  /"   
printn "     \/__/" 
printn "Welcome to Sheridan"

call cleanScreen

printn "      ___"     
printn "     /  /\"    
printn "    /  /:/_"   
printn "   /  /:/ /\"  
printn "  /  /:/ /::\" 
printn " /__/:/ /:/\:\"
printn " \  \:\/:/~/:/"
printn "  \  \::/ /:/" 
printn "   \__\/ /:/"  
printn "     /__/:/"   
printn "     \__\/"                       
printn "Welcome to Sheridan"

call cleanScreen

printn "      ___"     
printn "     /  /\"    
printn "    /  /::\"   
printn "   /__/:/\:\"  
printn "  _\_ \:\ \:\" 
printn " /__/\ \:\ \:\"
printn " \  \:\ \:\_\/"
printn "  \  \:\_\:\" 
printn "   \  \:\/:/"  
printn "    \  \::/"   
printn "     \__\/"    
printn "Welcome to Sheridan"  

cleanScreen proc
INT 10h
mov AH,0
cleanScreen endp 

enterText:  ;if ESC is press then get String and Print it
call get_string                
call print_string                                                      
RET                       

hlt
define_print_string
define_get_string
end
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This code makes no sense.

```
cleanScreen proc
INT 10h
mov AH,0
cleanScreen endp
```

If you want to clean the screen by setting it anew then use

```
cleanScreen proc
mov al,3   ;Video mode number
mov ah,0   ;Function number
INT 10h
cleanScreen endp
```

To wait for the ESC key use this code

```
enterText:  ;if ESC is press then get String and Print it
mov ah,0
int 16h
cmp al,27
jne enterText
```

p.s. Nice ASCII-art.